# CFQ scheduling algorithm

Tags: scheduling, hard-drive

The CFQ algorithm uses an ordered set of queues based on the I/O priority of the processes that made the requests. That means there's a queue for process of priority, let say, 1, another one for priority 2, etc.

I understand that the algorithm takes the first request from each queue, sort them (for avoiding unnecessary head movements)  and place them into a dispatch queue for being handle. But since a single request can have many blocks to read (not necessarily contiguous), how is this sort possible? I mean, if I have:

```
Request1 = [1,2,345,6,423]
```

and

```
Request2 = [3,4,2344,664]
```

being [a,b,c] a list of the blocks a, b and c, how are the resquests 1 and 2 placed into the dispatch queue? As you can see they have a non empty intersection (for example the block 6 is after the blocks 3 and 4)

Other thing I don't get is, again, since a request can have multiples blocks to read, what kind of scheduling is made inside of it? FCFS? or does it order the blocks?

For example, let's say we have a request that contains the following list of blocks to read:

```
[1,23,5,76,3]
```

How would the algorithm handle this?

by FCFS:

```
[1,23,5,76,3]
```

or by sorting the blocks:

```
[1,3,4,23,76]
```

Maybe I didn't understand the algorithm, couldn't find enough documentation. If anyone have a link o paper with a more detailed explanation, please refer me to it.

Answer (score 0):

I my understandig, CFQ does not schedule single track requests, but timeslices for a number of requests.
Quote from [IA64wiki](http://www.gelato.unsw.edu.au/IA64wiki/LinuxIOSchedulers):

> The CFQ scheduler aims to distribute disk time fairly amongst
>   processes competing for access to the disk. In addition, it uses
>   anticipation and deadlines to improve performance, and attempt to
>   bound latency.
>
> Each process issuing I/O gets a time slice during which it has
>   exclusive access for synchronous requests. The time slice is bounded
>   by two parameters: `slice_sync` adjusted by the process's I/O priority
>   gives the length in milliseconds of each slice; and `quantum` gives the
>   number of requests that can be issued.
>
> All processes share a set of 17 queues for asynchronous I/O, one for
>   each effective I/O priority. Each queue gets a time slice based on
>   `slice_async` adjusted by priority), and the queues are treated
>   round-robin.
>
> Within each slice, requests are merged (both front and back), and
>   issued according to SCAN, with backward seeks up to `back_seek_max`
>   permitted, but biassed by `back_seek_penalty` compared with forward
>   seeks. CFQ will wait up to `slice_idle` ms within a slice for a process
>   to issue more I/O. This allows anticipation, and also improves
>   fairness when a process issues bursty I/O; but in general it reduces
>   performance.